# Randomize two arrays and output the same "randomized" result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using JavaScript/jQuery to random two list of arrays, one with the word and the other there definition.

I want each load to select 5 out of the available 10 in each array so that were I am running into issues.

I am able to randomize both arrays but I need both to output the same "random" result so they can match both sides.

```
var match1 = ["1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]; 
var match2 = ["1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
```

and is current output is something like

```
match1 = 2 5 7 8 3
match1 = 1 3 9 4 5
```

and I need somthing like this

```
match1 = 7 5 2 8 1
match1 = 7 5 2 8 1
```

I am new to JavaScript so sorry for the messy code.

```
function createQuizLayout() {
    //this are the draggables (#leftCol)
    var match1 = ["1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10"
    ];

    //this are drop target (#rightCol)
    var match2 = ["1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10"
    ];


    function randomSort(min, max) {
        return (parseInt(Math.random() * 10) % 2);
    }

    (match1.sort(randomSort));
    (match2.sort(randomSort));

    var arrMatch1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < match1.length; i++) {
        arrMatch1.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match1[i] + '</li>');
        arrMatch1.length = arrMatch1.length < 5 ? arrMatch1.length : 5;
    }

    var arrMatch2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < match2.length; i++) {
        arrMatch2.push('<li data-index="' + (i + 1) + '">' + match2[i] + '</li>');
        arrMatch2.length = arrMatch2.length < 5 ? arrMatch2.length : 5;
    }

    //shuffle the arrays
    arrMatch1 = shuffle(arrMatch1);
    arrMatch2 = shuffle(arrMatch2);

    //insert them into DOM
    $('#source').html(arrMatch1.join(''));
    $('#target').html(arrMatch2.join(''));
}

function shuffle(v) {
    for (var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Instead of 2 arrays, maybe you could create 1 array that has objects and each object holds the 2 pieces of data.

Comment: `shuffle(match1)` and then just do `match2 = match1.slice()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you missed the part **How to shuffle the two arrays the right (same) way** `:)`

Have a look at this code:

```js
var match1 = ["1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]; 
var match2 = ["1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]; 

var i=0, len= match1.length, next, order=[];
while(i<len)order[i]= ++i;
order.sort(function(){return Math.random()-.5});

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    next=order[i];
    match1.push(match1[next]);
    match2.push(match2[next]);
}
match1.splice(1, len);
match2.splice(1, len);

console.log(match1)
console.log(match2)
```

To change your arrays in place, get the shuffled order first and add the new arrangements to the end of the existing array `(match1)`.

Then splice out from index 1 splits the array into your two (same way shuffled) arrays with exactly the same length.